# Ontology OWL import from Excel to XML

Tags: xml, excel, jena, owl, ontology

I've got a project to my studies about owl. I need to extract datas from excel file and need to write them to xml file. I need to generate xml file with sensors and measurements using owl ontology. I don't know how to do it using jena apache. There's a data in excel: [Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRubj.jpg) . Can someone help me understand how to did it?

@edit: Instead of excel can be csv.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should understand what you are dealing with: what is a tabular (CSV or Exel) file, what is RDF, what is an ontology and how it is encoded in RDF, through OWL, what it means to map your tabular data into RDF and according to some OWL ontology, which might be already available or to be built by you (using a tool like Protegé). Then you have to understand the role of Jena as a library to manipulate RDF/OWL data programmatically, from Java.

Then, presumably, you'll have to write a Java program that loads your data from CSV (convert into CSV from Excel and then use the [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) library for that, you could [load straight from .xlsx files](https://www.callicoder.com/java-read-excel-file-apache-poi/), but probably it's harder to do for a newbie programmer), then use the data to create RDF triples and eventually save the RDF dataset using the XML serialisation for your RDF.

By the way, unless your homework requires you to use Jena, the CSV->RDF conversion can be done with a tool like [TARQL](http://tarql.github.io/). Once you know a bit of the [SPARQL](https://jena.apache.org/tutorials/sparql.html) language to query RDF, this approach is much simpler to use for the task.

Answer (score 0):

Apache Jena supports both RDF/XML and [CSV](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/csv/) formats (but the last one is only for reading). To convert CSV->XML need to include into maven pom.xml `org.apache.jena:jena-csv` artifact in additional to the main lib `org.apache.jena:jena-arq` (which include also jena ontology api, sparql, etc).

The working example:

```
    Model m = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
    // read csv:
    try (InputStream is = Test_CSV.class.getResourceAsStream("/test.csv")) {
        RDFDataMgr.read(m, is, "http://example.org", Lang.CSV);
    }
    // print to console:
    m.write(System.out, "ttl");
    // save as XML:
    Path p = Files.createTempFile("temp-", ".xml");
    System.out.println("Save to " + p);
    try (OutputStream out = Files.newOutputStream(p)) {
        RDFDataMgr.write(out, m, Lang.RDFXML);
    }
    // print file to console:
    Files.lines(p).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Also you can wrap just loaded graph as `org.apache.jena.ontology.OntModel`, which allows to work with ontology data in terms of OWL1 specification:

`OntModel o = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(OntModelSpec.OWL_DL_MEM, m);`

Comment: Where I need to put my file? Couse I tried everywhere but always NPE

Comment: @DuszeQ94 then you should read the Javadoc and understand what `getResourceAsStream` is doing. And what a class loader in Java is doing.